# Complex imaging matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I got a question regarding complex imaging matrices, its from an old exam in my Linear algebra course.

There's a long question about different imaging matrices, but my question is;

let say we have a imaging matrix $f: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $z \rightarrow (3+7i)z$, in this part the professor assumes that $f$ is bijective with its inverse $f^{-1}: z \rightarrow \frac{z}{(7+3i)}$.

My question is, can we always make this assumption in complex imaging matrices? Or can someone give me a example of a similar imaging matrix that is not bijective?

Comment: What is an imaging matrix?

Comment: Sorry, might be the wrong translation to English, is it transformation matrix?

Comment: If you mean that f is a linear map, then $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C: z\mapsto a\cdot z$ is bijective for any $a\in \mathbb C, a\neq 0$.
The inverse is $z\mapsto a^{-1}\cdot z$.

Comment: @Desperado: Sounds like a mistranslation of German *Abbildungsmatrix* or Swedish *avbildningsmatris*, or something similar. "Transformation matrix" is indeed the usual English term.

Answer (score 0):

Any field $K$ can be regarded as $K$-vector space, and every linear map $f:K\to K$ is of the form $f(x)= a\cdot x$ for  $a\in K$.
In this case the transformation matrix is simply $(a)$.

If $a=0$ the map is neither injective nor surjective, but for $a\neq 0$ the map is bijective with inverse map provided by $x \mapsto a^{-1} \cdot x$.